# How to remove a "lost" task bar in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-mars

In my eclipse Mars I have two task bars with only red corners as items:

[image]

How can I remove this both task bars? I have already disable all checkboxes under "Window" - "Perspective" - "Customize Perspective...". The both toolbars are still there. Also I cannot do a left or right click on these both toolbars ...

**EDIT:**

Ok, after reinstalling the "JBoss Developer Studio" PlugIn I get (instead of the red corners):

[image]

But I still cant remove these toolbars ...

Comment: Have you tried **Window** > **Perspective** > **Reset Perspective...**?

Comment: @E-Riz: Yes, I had tried that too ... without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file where the workbench layout is stored is

`<your-workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`

I had something similar happen once and was able to manually edit that file (with some trial-and-error) to get rid of the duplicate, unwanted toolbars. I can't really recommend it, though, as it's a very error-prone process. If you do decide to attempt it, make sure to make backups of the file before you being.

Alternatively, you can try just deleting that file (rename it or move it somewhere else) and see if Eclipse will re-create it automatically.

A better alternative is probably to export your workspace preferences then create a new workspace. You can import your projects and exported preferences into the new one.

Comment: Thanks. There was several "children" elements of type"menu:ToolBar" which I have delete. For me it was easy to find these entries because there was so many entries with the same icon .... :-)